# Run local SQL script file from Windows Command Prompt to update remote SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, batch-file, cmd

I am working with a SQL file which will update the data to a remote database. My SQL file is ok. Now the requirement is to run this SQL file from a command prompt. Is there any way to run this SQL file from command prompt or batch file?

I am using SQL Server 2012 and the SQL file is on my local machine.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have tried to connect using the `sqlcmd` by my database connection failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can run the SQL file from command prompt. Use `sqlcmd` for this.
You can find the documentation for `sqlcmd` here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

**EDIT:**
You can use the below code for this. You have to place the value for the variables for your own:

```
sqlcmd -e -x -r -b -W -U %user% -S %server% -d %db_name% -P %pass% -i %sqlfile% -r1
```

Set the value of `%server%` as `serverIP\instancename`

**EDIT 2:**
Full script should be close to this one:

```
    Set scriptfile=InsertDB.sql
    Set dbserver=
    set /p dbserver=Database Server :
    Set dbname=
    set /p dbname=Database Name :
    Set usrname=
    set /p usrname=Database Username : 
    Set passw=
    set /p passw=Database Password: 
    set scriptPath=%~dp0
    sqlcmd -e -x -r -b -s"| ", -W -U %usrname% -S %dbserver%  -d %dbname% -P %passw% -i "%scriptPath%%scriptfile%" -r1
    Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Many thanks. Can I set the variable values by getting values from the user?

Comment: This command cannot connect to the database. Is there anything I am missing?